# Entering Unicode Characters with `ssh ... tmux -CC a -t mySession` on iTerm2

Tags: ssh, iterm, tmux

When I ssh into the server and then open tmux, I'm able to enter in Unicode characters. It seems that the problem is specifically with sshing directly with `tmux -CC a -t mySession`.

Edit:
I'm trying to enter unicode characters from my keyboard into text files on my EC2 Ubuntu server with iTerm2 on my macbook using tmux. When I ssh directly into the server and attach to a tmux session, I'm able to enter in unicode characters. If, however, I ssh into tmux directly with the command `ssh -i my.pem ubuntu@ec2_domain.com -t 'tmux -CC a -t mySession'`, I'm unable to enter Unicode characters.

Comment: Did you try to use the `-t` switch to `ssh`?

Comment: @Jakuje Didn't work.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about exactly what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed fixed w/ Iterm2 3.0.15 and tmux 2.5+ https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/4664